# How to I get the set the value of an environment variable from the return value of a docker run command in a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins

I have a docker container that returns a value greater than or equal to 0, if I run the container locally I get a return value:

```
docker build -t tmp -f Dockerfile .
id=$(docker run --rm -v /mnt/BARAT_Data1/Weather_Files/NOAA_Forecasts:/weather_dir tmp)
echo $id  # Prints 0
```

I put this inside my jenkins script:

```
        stage("Run download process") {
            when {
                expression{currentBuild.currentResult == 'SUCCESS'}
            }
            steps {
                sh """
                docker rm -f sync_noaa || true
                rm -rf ${WEATHER_DIR}/staging/*
                """
                script {
                    env.NUM_PROCESSED=sh(script:'docker run --rm -v ${WEATHER_DIR}:/weather_dir ${DOCKER_TAG}', returnStdout: true).trim()
                }
                sh """
                echo ${env.NUM_PROCESSED}
                """
            }
        }
```

However this is printing `env.NUM_PROCESSED` as `null`.

I have tried different ways of doing this from related questions about setting the value of a jenkins environment variable from a shell command, but nothing I have tried has worked.

How to I get the set the value of an environment variable from the return value of a docker run command?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mutateable global varaible by adding:

```
import groovy.transform.Field
@Field def num_processed
```

before the `pipeline`. You can then modify, and print, the value of the variable by doing:

```
        stage("Run download process") {
            when {
                expression{currentBuild.currentResult == 'SUCCESS'}
            }
            steps {
                sh """
                docker rm -f sync_noaa || true
                rm -rf ${WEATHER_DIR}/staging/*
                """
                script {
                    num_processed = sh(
                        script: "docker run --rm -v ${WEATHER_DIR}:/weather_dir ${DOCKER_TAG}",
                        returnStdout: true
                    ).trim()
                    echo num_processed
                }
            }
        }
```